# Jquery Fixed Floating Div

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

I am using jquery for fixed floating div on scrolling, I have applied some style with top property on div and with jquery I am changing the top value. The problem is when I scroll till end, the div goes down and when I scroll till up, the div goes up direction(not where I placed it initially)
How can I check if user has scrolled till end and Up?
Below is my code

```
<div id="floatdiv" style="position:absolute;top:200px;left:58%;margin-left:235px;width:200px;">
</div>

var name = "#floatdiv";
    var menuYloc = null;
    menuYloc = parseInt($(name).css("top").substring(0, $(name).css("top").indexOf("px")))

$(window).scroll(function () {
 offset = menuYloc + $(document).scrollTop() + "px";
        $(name).animate({ top: offset }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
});
```

I want to give top: 200px in case of scroll till end and scroll till top
Or suggest some alternate code for fixed floating div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do I understand this right:

You want a DIV which is fix at top 200 Pixel and left 235 Pixel. It is supposed to stay on this position in the window, while you scroll.

Why not use CSS:

```
position: fixed
```

instead of

```
position: absolute
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked with this, but now on scrolling down, its moving the div to down side instantly

Comment: Do you still use your Javascript-Code? You don't have to, position:fixed should fix it on this window-position. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: So, get rid of it, at least of the code, you've posted above :)

Comment: I want the div to float on scrolling but on bottom most(when scrolling ends) it don't float, same as in case of top most,I want its top to be 200px